# Suppose that $f, g$ are continuous on $[a,b]$. Show that if $f=g$ a.e. on $[a,b]$, then in fact $f=g$ on $[a,b]$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose that $f, g$ are continuous on $[a,b]$. Show that if $f=g$ a.e. on $[a,b]$, then in fact $f=g$ on $[a,b]$.

If $f=g$ a.e. on $[a,b]$, then $m(\{x \in [a,b] \mid f(x)\ne g(x)\}) = 0$. How can we conclude the fact that $f=g$ on $[a,b]$? I have that $\{x \in [a,b] \mid f(x)\ne g(x)\} \subset [a,b]$ so $$m(\{x \in [a,b] \mid f(x)\ne g(x)\}) =0\le m([a,b])= b-a$$ but no help from this.

Comment: Hint: $f-g=0$ a.e., and use continuity.

Comment: The complement of a set of measure $0$ is dense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [functions $f=g$ $\lambda$-a.e. for continuous real-valued functions are then $f=g$ everywhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76202/functions-f-g-lambda-a-e-for-continuous-real-valued-functions-are-then-f)